# Saving And Loading Integers errors Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am having a problem saving and loading up my difficulty integer. I have a button pushed to decide it on one view:

(This is one difficulty)

```
Difficulty + 1

    let SecondDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    SecondDefaults.setObject(Difficulty, forKey: "Difficulty")
    SecondDefaults.synchronize()
```

On another view under viewDidLoad for the loading:

```
let SecondDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var difficulty = SecondDefaults.valueForKey("Difficulty")?.integerValue
        SecondDefaults.synchronize()
        Difficulty = difficulty!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet).toInt()!
```

Comment: What kind of object is Difficulty? is it a Swift Integer?

Comment: It is just an Integer.

Comment: How/where are you setting Difficulty? And why are you retrieving it as a string if it's an int?

Comment: @SRL: Check whether that page exist or not also check whether your condition is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
var difficulty = SecondDefaults.valueForKey("Difficulty") as? String
```

to

```
var difficulty = SecondDefaults.valueForKey("Difficulty")?.stringValue
```

I don't know why you need to convert the integer to string. You only need the following code for getting an integer from NSUserDefaults no need to convert it to string.

```
let SecondDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var difficulty = SecondDefaults.valueForKey("Difficulty")?.integerValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies on this line:

`var difficulty = SecondDefaults.valueForKey("Difficulty") as? String`

The problem is that the value may be a String or it may nil. Who knows? The `as?` keyword indicates that the cast may fail, so difficulty is a String optional, which you implicitly unwrap. Anything you unwrap as nil will give you a runtime error.

Assuming that `Difficulty` from your second code snippet is of type `Int`, this should work:

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let maybeDifficulty = defaults.valueForKey("Difficulty") as? Int
if let difficulty = maybeDifficulty {
  Difficulty = difficulty
} else {
  println("Difficulty is not an Int or may be nil")
}
```